# Which of the prequels are canon to Persona 5 - Strikers?

Tags: persona-5, persona-5-royal, persona-5-strikers

I just watched a review of Persona 5 The Strikers and learned that its not a redo like The Royale, but a sequel.

But you have kind of 2 versions of the story before. Persona 5 and Persona 5: The Royale. The differences are small, but still, which one of the two is the canon? Do I have to play The Royale to get some events of Strikers or is is starting from the end of Persona 5 (Basic)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Persona 5 Strikers is a sequel to Persona 5. There are no references to the additional characters or new palace/semester that Royal introduces in Strikers. This seems to be more related to the development timelines than a choice in canon, as both Royal and Strikers were simultaneously under development.

There are a few sources that support this, including:
https://attackofthefanboy.com/guides/is-persona-5-strikers-a-sequel/